# While using text form in proof,how to use in same alignment in latex

Tags: align, text

How to write this text code in alignment?

```
\begin{align}
\text{2 $\times$ value of 1 step algo $\ge$ total value of 2nd (l+1)th item}
\text{Or, 2$\times$ value of 1 step algo $\ge$ total value of solution}    
\end{align}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve isn't clear to me. Could you explain with more details?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a choice to make: Do you want alignment on the `\ge` symbols or on the beginnings of the two "sentences"? Here's how these choices look like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{2 $\times$ value of 1 step algo} &\ge \text{total value of 2nd (l+1)th item}\\
\text{Or, 2 $\times$ value of 1 step algo} &\ge \text{total value of solution}     
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\text{2 $\times$ value of 1 step algo} \ge \text{total value of 2nd (l+1)th item}\\
&\text{Or, 2 $\times$ value of 1 step algo} \ge \text{total value of solution}     
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you seem to understand the question, please edit it so it is clearer.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - Well, I'm not sure if I really understood the question... Anyway, I edited it to replace the `\intertext` macros with `\text`. :-)